# mutagen or eyed3: identify and read ID3v1

Tags: python, id3, mutagen, eyed3

Most of my MP3 files are tagged with both ID3v1 and ID3v2. I want to write a script to read the files and identify ID3v1 versions, regardless of additional ID3 versions.

I'm struggling with the following code (*eyed3*). `isV1` is only `True` if ID3v1 is the only used version. But the code prints

> V1 > False
>
> V2 > True

for files with ID3v1 and ID3v2.

The code uses *eyed3* but I'd also accept *mutagen* (but could not find an example how to code it).

```
import eyed3
a = eyed3.load("song.mp3")
print("V1", a.tag.isV1())
print("V2", a.tag.isV2())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In [`eyed3.id.tag.parse()`](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/eyed3/id3/tag.html) you can see that if ID3v2 is found then no potential ID3v1 is loaded anymore.
- In [`eyed3.core.load()`](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/eyed3/core.html) you can see that the function has not only 1 parameter for the filename, but also a 2nd for which tag version you want to find/load.
- The available constants for that parameter can be found in [`eyed3.id3`](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/eyed3/id3.html) - you are most likely interested in any version of ID3v1 and any version of ID3v2.

Combining that knowledge you have to load the file twice and act upon it:

```
v1 = eyed3.load("song.mp3", ID3_V1)
print("V1", v1.tag.isV1())

v2 = eyed3.load("song.mp3", ID3_V2)
print("V2", v2.tag.isV2())
```

Comment: thanks @AmigoJack that worked, i used (1, None, None) for ID3_V1.